# "hide" a UIView that has subviews with autolayout

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

I want to hide a `UIView` that contains some subviews depending on a boolean.

The `UIView` has more elements below it, so I put 0 in the Height constraint constant.

The thing is that the subviews won't go away with it

How can I eliminate them without iterating all elements and fix their height as well?

Comment: `_yourView.clipsToBounds = TRUE;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set `clipsToBounds` property of your hidden view to YES ("Clip Subviews" in interface builder)